# getting top level parent attribute value

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

i am customizing a plugin named **Juqery FIler** which is used for uploading multiple images to the server via ajax.

now what i did is after uploading the image the plugin generates some html for displaying and deleting the image i copied that code and pasted in inside my edit view here my code!

now if you notic the b tag it contains the name of the file which i need to delete the file from the server but i couldnt get it.

this is what i tried so far!

```
<?php foreach($images as $i):?>   
<li class="jFiler-item <?=($i['is_main']==1)?'before':'';?>" data-jfiler-index="0" style="" data-jfiler-index-new="<?=$i['id']?>">
    <div class="jFiler-item-container">
        <div class="jFiler-item-inner">
            <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">
                <div class="jFiler-item-status">
                </div>
                <div class="jFiler-item-thumb-overlay">
                    <div class="jFiler-item-info">
                        <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                        <span class="jFiler-item-title">
                            <b title="<?=$i['path']?>"><?=$i['path']?></b>
                        </span>
                        <span class="jFiler-item-others">58.1 KB</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jFiler-item-thumb-image">
                <img src="<?=base_url()."uploads/".$i['path']?>" draggable="false">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">
                <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
                    <li>
                        <div class="jFiler-jProgressBar" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="bar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="jFiler-item-others text-success" style="">
                            <i class="icon-jfi-check-circle"></i> Success
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                    <li>
                        <a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endforeach;?>

$(".icon-jfi-trash").on("click", function () {
    //alert($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr("data-jfiler-index-new"));
    console.log($(this).closest("b").text());
});
```

but it is still not working any help?

Comment: Closest traverses the ancestors of $(this), the b element is a child of another div that is not an ancestor of your trash icon link node.

Comment: i also tried parent() but still couldn't get t it.

Comment: added an answer below which should do what you need

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
  $(".icon-jfi-trash").on("click",function(){
        //Use closest to grab the ancestor container div, then use find() to grab 
//the b element decendant of the container div as the container div is an ancestor of both
         console.log($(this).closest(".jFiler-item-container").find('b').text());
```

Comment: Oh perfect! i forgot the find attribute thumbs up.

Comment: @uneebmeer No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: one more thing please?

Comment: can i get the attribute also?

Comment: basically i want this attribute also => data-jfiler-index-new

Comment: You can use .attr('data-jfiler-index-new') instead of .text() to grab it's attribute.